# Node.js — Google OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications -> How to use the token event

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to figure out how to use the token event as specified in Google's OAuth 2.0 documentation for [server side applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) (using Node.js):

Here's the code for the token event:

```
oauth2Client.on('tokens', (tokens) => {
  if (tokens.refresh_token) {
    // store the refresh_token in your secure persistent database
    console.log(tokens.refresh_token);
  }
  console.log(tokens.access_token);
});
```

I actually get this event to fire, but am unsure about when to check for a valid token. If I do this one every request (let's say Google Docs API request), the token event fires after I'm requesting the API, so credentials are not set correctly.

How would you go about making sure that the correct access token is set BEFORE making a request?

Google says "**Once the client has a refresh token, access tokens will be acquired and refreshed automatically in the next call to the API.**", which is also kind of the case, but too late.

So my question once again: How do I, in my call, wait for the token event to finish updating my access token in order to set credentials BEFORE making the request?

Thank you!